Alternative for lazyTraceExecutor in springBoot 3.x upgrade
I am replacing spring-cloud-sleuth with io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave for my springboot:3.x upgrade. Can you confirm if below replacement is correct?
public LazyTraceExecutor createNewLazyTraceExecutorFromExecutorService(ExecutorService threadPool)
{
 BeanFactory beanFactory = SpringApplicationContextProvider.getBeanFactory(); 
 return new LazyTraceExecutor(beanFactory, threadPool);
} 


public ExecutorService createNewLazyTraceExecutorFromExecutorService(ExecutorService threadpool)
    {
        BeanFactory beanFactory = SpringApplicationContextProvider.getBeanFactory();
        return ContextExecutorService.wrap(taskExecutor.getThreadPoolExecutor(), ContextSnapshotFactory.builder().build()::captureAll);
    }

Also LazyTraceExecutor provides implementation for Executor.execute(); Can I use ContextExecutorService now?
